# How to download PDF file from files on button click?

Tags: c#, pdf

I want to dowlnload a PDF file on a button click. I've try like that:

```
 protected void lbtnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lbtnDownload.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            else if (lbtnDownload.Text.EndsWith(".pdf"))
            {
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            }

            string filePath = lbtnDownload.Text;

            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + filePath + "\"");
            Response.TransmitFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/") + "\\PDF\\" + filePath );
            Response.End();
        }

    }
```

But nothing happens, I mean when I debug it there is no exception, but the file is not downloading.

Does anyone knows where my mistake is, and what I should do to download the PDF?

Comment: From where should the file be downloaded? Is it a UAC-Path (like `\\Computername\anyshare\anyfile.extension`) or a HTTP Server? (like `anysite.tld/file.ext` or `127.0.0.1/file.ext`)

Comment: Its a UAC-Path its not HTTP Server

Comment: Try to add `Response.Flush();` before `Response.End();`

Comment: I get this error in Console:-

Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed.

Comment: I fixed it. The problem was becouse of the UpdatePanel that I use. I added a PostBackTrigger and everything works fine now. Thank you

Comment: So `Response.Flush();` fixed it in general?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtName.Text)) return;            

        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + txtName.Text);
        string filePath = Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/SavedFolder/PDF", txtName.Text));
        Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: I dont have a "Combine" option..  :( I can't use Path.Combine

Comment: It is on System.IO namespace  System.IO.Path.Combine, or you can just replace it with "~/SavedFolder/PDF/" + txtName.Text

Comment: I fixed it. The problem was becouse of the UpdatePanel that I use. I added a PostBackTrigger and everything works fine now. Thank you